# Spring Cloud Contract with TestNG

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

As far as I understand(beginner level on Spring Cloud Contract), the contract tests generated from the groovy contracts are with junit. 
What if I want to use TestNG? Basically I want to group my tests with TestNG annotation `@Test(groups="unit")` and `@Test(groups="contract")` in order to separate unit tests and contract tests using ssomething like `mvn test -Dgroups=unit` and `mvn test -Dgroups=contract`.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, we don't support this out of the box. You would have to write your own `org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.builder.SingleTestGenerator` implementation (by extending, for example, the `JavaTestGenerator` and referencing it in `spring.factories` file) but that can be quite time-consuming, unfortunately.